# Character-Matrix - how to operate by row?

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining

I have a matrix of character data

```
charMatrix <- structure(c("Bolt", "Nut Plate", "Magnet", "", "Clevis", "welded", 
     "", "Receptacle"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))

[,1]            [,2]        
[1,] "Bolt"      "Clevis"    
[2,] "Nut Plate" "welded"    
[3,] "Magnet"    ""          
[4,] ""          "Receptacle"
```

I want to `paste` the rows together and `trim` them to get the vector.

```
[1] "Bolt Clevis" "Nut Plate welded" "Magnet" "Receptacle"
```

I solved it this way, but I think there must be something much simpler, either in Base R or Tidyverse.

```
vec <- charMatrix %>% t() %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>% 
  summarise_all(~ str_trim(paste(., collapse = " "))) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.character()

vec
[1] "Bolt Clevis"      "Nut Plate welded" "Magnet"           "Receptacle"
```

Can you show me a more direct way to get this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a matrix you can use rowwise `apply` and `trimws` to remove leading/trailing whitespaces

```
trimws(apply(charMatrix, 1, paste, collapse = ' '))
#[1] "BoltClevis"      "Nut Platewelded" "Magnet"          "Receptacle"
```

Or remove empty values and paste.

```
apply(charMatrix, 1, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse = ' '))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` by converting the `matrix` to `data.frame` and use `paste` with `do.call`

```
trimws(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(charMatrix)))
#[1] "Bolt Clevis"      "Nut Plate welded" "Magnet"           "Receptacle"
```

The `do.call` is vectorized and would be fast compared to looping.

---

Or using simple subsetting and `paste`

```
trimws(paste(charMatrix[,1], charMatrix[,2]))
```

Both are vectorized.  The OP's question is to apply the function directly.  Both of the solutions does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

charMatrix %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  unite("Var", sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Var = str_trim(Var)) %>% 
  pull()
```